# what line drawing algorithm is used in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, algorithm, html5-canvas

if I draw a line in HTML5 Canvas in the Chrome browser, what line drawing algorithm is used?

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

I have a very particular customer and they want to know exactly how are we drawing lines.

There are many line drawing algorithms, but what algorithm(s) is used in HTML5 Canvas ?

Comment: Depends on the graphic sub-system of the OS.

Comment: Chrome uses the Blink rendering engine, and Blink is open source. You could start your search for the implementation in [class CanvasRenderingContext2d](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/html/canvas/CanvasRenderingContext2D.cpp)